# Getting error "binary '[' : 'const typ' does not define this operator" or "subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c++, arrays

In a template class I've got a function that inserts a numb-elements array in another array from selected index.

```
template <class T>
void my_vect<T> ::insert(const T &ob, size_t ind, size_t numb)
{
    int i, j = 0;
    if (ind == last + 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < numb; i++)
            push(ob[i]);
    }
    else if (ind > last + 1)
        msg.mess(my_mess::WARN_ARR_SMALL);
    else
    {
        if (last + numb > ndim)
        {
            msg.mess(my_mess::WARN_ARR_FULL);
            realloc();
        }

        last += numb;
        for (i = last; i = (ind + numb); i--)
        {
            dat[i] = dat[i - numb];
        }

        for (i = ind; i < (ind + numb); i++)
            dat[i] = ob[j++];
    }
}
```

I also have an interface class and I have a managing insert function there

```
void my_interf::insertarr()
{
    typ *ob = NULL;
    size_t ind, numb, i;
    cout << "Podaj indeks: ";
    cin >> ind;
    cout << "Podaj ilosc elementow tablicy: ";
    cin >> numb;
    ob = new typ[numb];
    for (i = 0; i < numb; i++)
    {
        cout << "Podaj " << i << " element tablicy: " << endl;
        cin >> ob[i];
    }
    vect.insert(*ob, ind, numb);
}
```

typ is typedef, when I put my another class type mcoord, I get an error

```
error C2676: binary '[' : 'const typ' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

mcoord.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my_mess.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class mcoord
{
protected:
    double *pcoord;
    my_mess msg;
public:
    mcoord(double xx, double yy);
    mcoord();
    mcoord(const mcoord &ob);
    ~mcoord() { delete[] pcoord; }
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &strm, const mcoord &ob);
    friend istream & operator >> (istream &strm, mcoord &ob);
    mcoord & operator = (const mcoord &ob);
    int operator == (const mcoord &praw) const;

private:
    void alloc();
};
```

and when I define typ as int I get error

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Both errors are in the template class in lines with ob[i] and ob[j++]. 
I couldn't find any solution, so I'll be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the function as:

```
template <class T>
void my_vect<T> ::insert(const T *ob, size_t ind, size_t numb)
```

In other words, make `ob` a pointer not a reference.